# Emgu exit unexpectedly after calling AdaptiveThreshold function

Tags: c#, opencv, dll, build, emgucv

I am totally new to emgu. I've been searching for a solution for this problem but I couldn't find any solution. I am trying to threshold a given Image using the built in adaptive threshold function but the program exits with no exception

Code :

```
 public Image<Gray, byte> AdaptiveThreshold(Image<Bgr, byte> bmp, int windowSize)
    {
        Image<Gray, byte> gray = new Image<Gray, byte>(bmp.ToBitmap());

        Image<Gray, byte> bw = gray.ThresholdAdaptive(new Gray(255), Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ADAPTIVE_THRESHOLD_TYPE.CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.THRESH.CV_THRESH_OTSU, windowSize, new Gray(0.03));
        return bw;
    }
```

Function call :

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = r.AdaptiveThreshold(this.bmp, 15).ToBitmap(); // here where the application exit with no error and with no output in pictureBox1
```

`r is an object of class which contains AdaptiveThreshold defined above`

I copied all un-manged binaries from bin folder emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.9.0.1922\bin\x86 to my debug folder, I also added Emgu Dlls to my project's references Emgu.CV, Emgu.CV.UI, Emgu.Util
I also set my target platform to x86 
I am working on visual studio 2013 under windows 8 .

Comment: What is exactly your question? I does not just seem like a problem when your application exits without any exception. I think that some details are missing. What is the expected outcome? Also some code calling this function might be helpfull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that for some reason the application is indeed exited when using `Emgu.CV.CvEnum.THRESH.CV_THRESH_OTSU` as threshold method for an adaptive threshold. The exact reason for this is yet unknown to me.

Though by reading the **documentation** of Open CV on the adaptive threshold functionality I've noticed that this is not valid value to be passed into this function. As found on [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html) page:

Parameters:

**src** – Source 8-bit single-channel image.

**dst** – Destination image of the same size and the same type as src .

**maxValue** – Non-zero value assigned to the pixels for which the condition is 
satisfied. See the details below.

**adaptiveMethod** – Adaptive thresholding algorithm to use, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C or ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C . See the details below.

**thresholdType** – Thresholding type that must be either THRESH_BINARY or THRESH_BINARY_INV .
blockSize – Size of a pixel neighborhood that is used to calculate a threshold value for the pixel: 3, 5, 7, and so on.

**C** – Constant subtracted from the mean or weighted mean (see the details below). Normally, it is positive but may be zero or negative as well.

So you will have to adjust your used `thresholdType` to either `Emgu.CV.CvEnum.THRESH.CV_THRESH_BINARY` or `Emgu.CV.CvEnum.THRESH.CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV` to let your function work.

Comment: Thank you sir for your effort I really appreciate it